# How create loop job to change/ convert type for multiple variables in r

Tags: r, loops

I need to replace integer variable to factor using this statement below I can accomplish my goal.

```
training$v1 <- factor(training$v1)
```

But I have 100 of these v1 to v100 : I'm trying to do the loop on this using this code .. but it gave me error.

```
for (i in 1:100) {
    training$vi <-factor(training$vi)
}
```

Any recommendation?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this inside the for loop

```
clm <- paste("v", i, sep = "")
training[, clm] <- factor(training[, clm]
```

or use column index instead. For instance, the columns you want to modify are from 2:101

```
for (i in 2:101) {
    training[, i] <- factor(training[, i])
}
```

Comment: I should note that `[clm]` would work as well, because when comma is not specified, R assumes we are subsetting data.frame columns. I like to be very explicit, it sometimes pays down the line.

Answer (score 4):

A one-line `dplyr` solution that doesn't use explicit loops:

```
training <- mutate_each(training, funs(factor), v1:v100)
```

Or equivalently, using piping and an alternative variable selector:

```
training <- training %>% mutate_each(funs(factor), num_range('v',1:100))
```

Etc, etc